# List<MyClass> from awaitable task

Tags: c#, database, list, sqlite, async-await

In my application, different canvases are stored as "pages", the contents of each canvas is stored as "cells".

Now when I want to load all cells that occupy / make up one canvas, I retrieve them like this:

```
public Task<List<Cell>> GetCellsAsync(string uPageGUID)
{
    return database.QueryAsync<Cell>("SELECT * FROM cells WHERE cellpageguid = ?", uPageGUID);
}
```

This works great.

Now I would like to find out the "pageguid" of the page that has the value "pageisstartpage" set to true.

Therefore I'm trying the following:

```
public Task<string>GetStartPageGUID()
{
    nPages<List<Page>>=database.QueryAsync<Page>("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageisstartpage=?", true);
    return nPages.First.GUID;
}
```

The compiler tells me:

> nPages doesn't exist in the current context.

I don't see where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> nPages doesn't exist in the current context....I don't see where I made a mistake.

The first thing to mention is that the declaration of the `List<Page>` seems backwards.

```
nPages<List<Page>>=database....
```

The type has to be written first followed by the variable name.

```
List<Page> nPagesTask = database...
```

Another interpretation could be that you have a generic type variable `nPages` in which you want to specify the generic type. So the compiler looks whether this variable has already been declared. And apparently it cannot find any.

The second thing If you have an async method that returns a `Task<string>` you could do the following:

```
public async Task<string>GetStartPageGUID()
{
    Task<List<Page>> nPagesTask = database.QueryAsync<Page>("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageisstartpage=?", true);
    List<Page> npages = await nPagesTask;
    return nPages.First().GUID;
}
```

Here is the [source](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLiteAsync.cs) of the `QueryAsync` method. this is the signature:

```
public Task<List<T>> QueryAsync<T> (string query, params object[] args)
```

so it returns a `Task<List<T>>`. Since your method specifies a different return type the usual pattern is to await it in a `async` method as described in [the MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx#BKMK_HowtoWriteanAsyncMethod) and then return the type that you specified in you method.

Comment: If you use `await` you need to define the method as `async`

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare nPages correctly:

```
List<Page> nPages = database.QueryAsync<Page>("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageisstartpage=?", true);
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. The compiler tells "Cannot implicitely convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<MyApp..Page>> to System.Collections.Generic.List<MyApp.Page>.

Comment: The compiler error is raised even without the line "return nPages.First.GUID;" so the error seems to be in the code that @Marc posted as his reply.